# Excluding one directory in .htaccess (not just rewrite rules)

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Excluding one or more directories from rewrite rules in .htaccess files seems to be a common question. However, my .htaccess does more than just set rewrite rules. I've also set some server changes (we don't have suPHP on this server) as well as set some prepending of some php files. For example these are a few examples:

```
    # Make files ending in .php, .html and .xml files etc. parsed by php.
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html .xml .css .js .le .txt

<FilesMatch "\.html$">
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/2427/spwebsites/www.spwebsites.co.uk/incs/phps/config.php"
</FilesMatch>
# Internal Server Error
ErrorDocument 500 /admin/errors.html?code=500
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

I don't want any of these set for one directory (where my word press installation is), is there a way I can do this? Can I set a conditional statement for the whole .htaccess file?

Adding a blank .htaccess file in the word press directory won't work because this won't undo the settings in the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just looking into your dilemma and it is a tricky one. It would be nice to be able to have the `DirectoryMatch` directive available in .htaccess ...

What you can try is to reset your values in the specific directory via another .htaccess file.

So in the case of the `AddType` perhaps, resetting it back to just ".php" might work (assuming it doesn't inherit the other values). Definitely not an ideal solution with out access to the main config file/ virtual host.

<strike>Here is a **weird idea** that you can try/test ... place the "wordpress" dir outside of the main root (or whereever you have the offending .htaccess file). Now route all requests to the wordpress (inner dir) to the outer dir. I wonder if Apache would not use the offending .htaccess considering the requests are being routed?</strike>

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Resetting the .htaccess may be the only way to do this, but it's going to be a real pain to implement. I'll have a go at implementing your idea and get back to you. Otherwise, is there really no other way?

Comment: I have managed to reset the bits in the .htaccess file that matter I think. I think your solution is going to be the best one. Thanks!